# Calendario con primefaces no despliega

Tags: java-ee

Hola quisiera saber si alguien  sabe por que el calendar de primeface no abre cuando doy click sobre su campo.

La imagen muestra como se queda el campo al dar clik sobre el.

el codigo de la pagina es el siguiente:

```
<ui:define name="cuerpo">
    <h:form prependId="false">

        <p:panel id="datosPanel" header="Datos Usuario">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">

                <h:outputText value="fecha" />

                <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt"
                    value="#{fechaController.date}" />

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.